# Navigate to new navigation page from ViewModel with Xamarin XLabs

Tags: mvvm, navigation, xamarin, viewmodel

I am trying to navigate to a new navigation page from a ViewModel

I have this snippet in my App.cs which makes a new navigation page and binds the ViewModel to the View

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage((Page)ViewFactory.CreatePage<MainViewModel, MainView>());
```

The snippet is from this article [getting started xamarin forms labs xaml mvvm ioc](http://www.codenutz.com/getting-started-xamarin-forms-labs-xaml-mvvm-ioc/) @ "5. Register the View with the ViewFactory"

But how would we do this in a ViewModel, and does it make sense to create a new page and bind the ViewModel and View together when we just binded them with ViewFactory.Register?

**Snippet from the article:**

```
public class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        RegisterViews();
        MainPage = new NavigationPage((Page)ViewFactory.CreatePage<MainViewModel, MainView>());
    }

    private void RegisterViews()
    {
        ViewFactory.Register<MainView, MainViewModel>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No sure I undersant your question well but, here is what I do : 
first in your AppDelegate (or main activity) register your Dependency Injection module (IDependencyContainer for a simpleContainer here):

```
        var resolverContainer = new SimpleContainer();
        UserService us = new UserService();

        var app = new XFormsAppiOS();
        resolverContainer.Register<IDevice>(t => AppleDevice.CurrentDevice)
            .Register<IDisplay>(t => t.Resolve<IDevice>().Display)
            .Register<IXFormsApp>(app)
            .Register<IJsonSerializer, JsonSerializer>()
            .Register<IDependencyContainer>(resolverContainer);
        Resolver.SetResolver(resolverContainer.GetResolver());
```

Then on your app.cs, be sure to register the navigation service to goes whith your main navigation page

```
Page loginPage = new NavigationPage((LoginPage)ViewFactory.CreatePage<LoginViewModel, LoginPage>());
MainPage = loginPage;
Resolver.Resolve<IDependencyContainer>()
   .Register<INavigationService>(t => new NavigationService(MainPage.Navigation)) //New Xlabs nav service
   .Register<INavigation>(t => MainPage.Navigation); // old Xlabs nav service
```

And in your viewModel push to page you need

```
await Resolver.Resolve<INavigation>().PushAsync((ParameterPage)ViewFactory.CreatePage<ParameterViewModel, ParameterPage>(), false);
```